# onclick() event in dropdown list items

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jsf

I have dropdown list label of "primary Carrier" which contains values for ex. Amazon, Waymart, Best-Buy and the values are coming from database and here is the condition I need to follow .. if primary carrier dropdown label is not  "Amazon" then need to display some options.

Here is my code:

```
<m:td width="250"

onclick="javascript:flagWarn=false;javascript:datechanged=true;javascript:addeditrow('claimSearchForm1');">
<h:outputLabel  for="primaryCarrier" value="Primary Carrier " />
<h:selectOneMenu id="primaryCarrier"
value="#{crossoverClaimDataBean.providerClaimVO.claimLineItemDetails.primaryCarrier}"
onchange="javascript:selectOne=true;"  >    
onclick=if(!amazon(this,'t1_options)

<f:selectItems value="#{crossoverClaimDataBean.primaryCarrierList}"  /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>

<m:div sid="t1_options" styleclass="hide">
<h:outputLabel for="lname6"
value="Other Insured's Last Name" />
<h:outputLabel for="mi6" value="MI" />
```

Please let me know my approach is correct or not. If not please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried any client-side approach (Javascript) for your requirement?

Comment: no ..can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Make some id for label `primaryCarrier` and get the text of this label. Finally check it is `Amazon` or others.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
<h:outputLabel id="primaryLabel" for="primaryCarrier" value="Primary Carrier"  />
<h:selectOneMenu id="primaryCarrier"
 value="#{crossoverClaimDataBean.providerClaimVO.claimLineItemDetails.primaryCarrier}"
 onchange="javascript:selectOne=true;"  >    
onclick=if(!amazon(this,'t1_options)

<f:selectItems value="#{crossoverClaimDataBean.primaryCarrierList}" />
```

And in your javascript,

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    //document is ready. Do your stuff here
    var labelValue = document.getElementById("primaryLabel").innerText;
     if(labelValue === 'Amazon'){

      } else {
         // Do the stuff here..
      }
    }
}
```

If you are using jQuery,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var labelValue = $("#primaryLabel").text();
    if(labelValue === 'Amazon'){

    } else {
         // Do the stuff here..
    }
});
```

Hope this helps..